# CentOS 7 guest fails to boot on Xenserver 7.0

Tags: linux, centos, xen, boot, xenserver

I have a CentOS 7 guest installed on a Xenserver 7.0 Host with all the up to date patches.  I have tried 2 installation sources, the minimal.iso and the DVD, and installed the 64bit version.  I have no installation issues but upon reboot I get the following screen.

[image: Boot Screen]

At this point the VM just sits there.  I have allotted 1 CPU with 2 cores to this VM.  The first core is pegged at 100% utilization. I have allocated 4GB RAM, so I don't think its a memory issue.  I have looked around on the net for similar issues and have found none.  There is a possibility this is related to the bochs video driver.  I had to disable it to get the graphic install working but I am unable to access the boot loader to modify the kernel options as I am with the installer.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a "Misc" vm template in xenserver and not using the CentOS 7 template.